# Why network button not working when I clicked it

Tags: network-manager

Sometimes I clicked this network button:

http://www.divshare.com/download/15716721-6fa

Why it doesn't work (just like I haven't clicked it)?

When it failed, only when I reboot,it works again.

Sometimes it failed again.

What could I do?

I use ubuntu 11.04 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when it doesn't work - `sudo service network-manager restart` . That will restart the network-manager applet.

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work then you can try this:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

which a temporary solution. It will work until you reboot. For more details and a permanent solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1895671

Comment: can you please provide details of the "permanent solution"?